# ROS Answers SE migration: Topic error

Tags: ros, topic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

Please help! When I doing catkin_make error occurs

```
[ERROR] [1446289007.910781560]: Client [/sh_serial] wants topic /sh_manager_out to have datatype/md5sum [sh_msgs/serial_out/df665c60bef6a942a36a48cdc754f59b], but our version has [sh_msgs/serial_out/5b158db7c862f136a87ffd4b4b6e5ae3]. Dropping connection.
```

I can not understand why. How to fix it?

Best regards Sergey

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220199/topic-error/) by [Sergey I.](https://answers.ros.org/users/24417/sergey-i./) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2015-10-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!
I found  solution. Just my mistake. I modified the serial_out.msg file and I modified the subscribe file in my project. The publisher file was not modified. I did catkin_make, rosrun my nodes and got an error, because the subscribe file has been compiled with the new header files serial_out.msg and the publisher file with the old. Everything was very simple.

P.S. Sorry for my english. I hope the meaning is clear. Thank you.

---

Originally posted by [Sergey I.](https://answers.ros.org/users/24417/sergey-i./) with karma: 16 on 2015-11-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0